# why I have a extra file when listing files from S3 folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to list the file from S3 Bucket "card-prtnr-npi". The files that I want to read are in the "ambs_ambivolatile" folder which is there in the S3  "card-prtnr-npi" bucket. This is the actual path "card-prtnr-npi/users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile". "ambs_ambivolatile" folder has only one file in it but Boto 3 is reading an additional file which is not present.

'users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/' is not present in the folder and only part-m-00026.bz2' is present. Please see the below code.

['users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/', 'users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/part-m-00026.bz2']

```
    s3_src_bucket = 'card-prtnr-npi'
    s3_src_prefix = 'users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/'
    print("getting response from source")
source_bucket = src_session.resource('s3').Bucket(s3_src_bucket)
files = source_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_src_prefix)
source_keys = []
for file in files:
    source_keys.append(file.key)

print(source_keys)
```

The above print statement prints the following list
['users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/', 'users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/part-m-00026.bz2']

How do I stop reading this extra file 'users/rtltest/ambs_ambivolatile/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a file, it's a prefix that you set. S3 has no concept of folders. Every file path is a single string, and you filtered for the start of it

Try this to exclude the prefix

```
source_keys = [file.key for file in files if file.key!=s3_src_prefix]
```